# ngannotate-rails not working in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby, coffeescript

I'm using ngannotate-rails to help get angular code to work in a compressed format. This is in a Rails 3.2 + Angular 1.5.x app.

I've added the following to my Gemfile and ran bundle

```
group :assets do
  gem 'sprockets-derailleur', '~> 1.0.0'          # Speed up precompiles with multi-core compile
  gem 'turbo-sprockets-rails3', '~> 0.3.14'       # Compile only changed assets
  gem 'sass-rails', ' ~> 3.2'                   # Main CSS extension in use
  gem 'less', '~> 2.6.0'                          # Less required for ui-utils plugin for AngularJS
  gem 'therubyracer', '~> 0.12.1'                 # v8 library required for less
  gem 'coffee-rails'                              # Language which compiles into JS
  gem 'uglifier'                      # JS parser, minifier, compressor or beautifier toolkit

  gem 'ngannotate-rails', '~> 1.2'                # AngularJS minifier
end
```

Then in config/environments/development.rb I've added the following

```
  if ENV['NG_FORCE'] == 'true'
    config.assets.compress = true
    config.assets.compile = true
    config.assets.digest = true
    config.assets.debug = false

    # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
    config.assets.precompile += %w(*.css *.js *.woff *.eot *.svg *.ttf) # The fix for font-awesome

  else
    # Do not compress assets
    config.assets.compress = false

    # Expands the lines which load the assets
    config.assets.debug = true
  end
```

I then do the following commands but ng-annotate is not annotating

```
NG_FORCE=true RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake assets:clean assets:precompile:primary
NG_FORCE=true rails s
```

I check the compiled output in public/assets/.../ and I get this at the top;

```
(function(){var e;e=function(e,n,t,i,o,c,r,a,u,d,s,l,v,f,g,h,m,p,b,k,y,I,T,E,q,w,A){var D,P,F,x,j;
```

It's minified but not annotated with the strings so AngularJS throws this error;

```
application-57db964b9323e90284f1f3c331c9c3aa.js:43 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: eProvider <- e <- InvoicesController
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/unpr?p0=eProvider%20%3C-%20e%20%3C-%20InvoicesController
    at http://localhost:3000/assets/application-57db964b9323e90284f1f3c331c9c3aa.js:41:28591
    at http://localhost:3000/assets/application-57db964b9323e90284f1f3c331c9c3aa.js:42:16654
    at Object.r [as get] (http://localhost:3000/assets/application-57db964b9323e90284f1f3c331c9c3aa.js:42:15610)
    at http://localhost:3000/assets/application-57db964b9323e90284f1f3c331c9c3aa.js:42:16739
    at r (http://localhost:3000/assets/application-57db964b9323e90284f1f3c331c9c3aa.js:42:15610)
    at o (http://localhost:3000/assets/application-57db964b9323e90284f1f3c331c9c3aa.js:42:15910)
    at Object.s [as instantiate] (http://localhost:3000/assets/application-57db964b9323e90284f1f3c331c9c3aa.js:42:16247)
    at http://localhost:3000/assets/application-57db964b9323e90284f1f3c331c9c3aa.js:43:9470
    at http://localhost:3000/assets/application-57db964b9323e90284f1f3c331c9c3aa.js:98:32136
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/assets/application-57db964b9323e90284f1f3c331c9c3aa.js:47:31053) <div id="wrapper" class="ui-wrapper ng-scope" ui-view="">
```

**UPDATE**

InvoicesController

```
InvoicesController = ($scope, $http, $location, $state, $stateParams, $uibModal, $timeout, flash, Invoice, Division, Costing, Job, JobService, Common, ShortcutService, InvoiceService, TimesheetService, DisbursementService, DebtorService, SearchService, LineItemService, DateService, $filter, $mdDialog, $mdMedia, Restangular, hotkeys) ->

<Snip: Too long>
  switch $state.current.name
    # Index

    when "invoices"
      $scope.query = SearchService.getFilter('invoices')
      page = SearchService.getPage('invoices')

      if ($scope.query)
        # Filter already exists
        $scope.filterForm = true
        getInvoices(angular.extend({}, $scope.query, {page: page, limit: 10, search: $scope.query}))
      else if page > 0
        $scope.query = { order: '-invoice_no', limit: 10,  page: page }
        $scope.onPaginate(page, 10)
      else
        $scope.resetFilter()

  <Snip>

angular
  .module('paisApp')
  .controller('InvoicesController', InvoicesController)
```

Comment: share your InvoicesController code

Comment: I don't see any "ngInject" at the top of your controller which is where you want it to annotate right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it might have been cut off in your snippet above, I don't see where you would have provided the "ngInject" directive in you code.

I would expect your controller code to look like

```
MyController = ($scope, ...) ->
  "ngInject"
  # etc
```

It's the `"ngInject"` that ng-annotate looks for as the hook in points when transpiling the code.

Comment: I didn't have the "ngInject" in my code as I thought that was only for ES6 and I'm using coffeescript. I guess coffeescript must compile down to ES6 and I have to put that line in. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it has to do with es6. I also use it with coffeescript but basically the npm module uses those code points to identify where you want an injection to be set up. There are also other ways to do it if you look at the npm docs but I've found this method the best and neatest using coffeescript. :)